# How to horizontally center 3 div elements with a dynamic width, first left, second center, third right?

Tags: css, html

I got three divs with dynamically changed with inside a parent div.
I need to align the first div left, the middle one has to be centered with the same padding to the left and right div, and the right one aligned to the right.

Sounds easy, but isn't (at least to me)!

[image: CoSharer/Privat&Offentlich/Abonnenten are the divs]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone did the following fiddle but edited the wrong way!
Unfortunately, I don`t know who did this.
Maybe spezzino, but I am not sure:

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap">

  <div class="left">
    left
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    right
  </div>

  <div class="center">
    center
  </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrap{
  text-align:center;
}

.left{
 float: left;
 background:grey
}

.right{
 float: right;
 background:red
}

.center{
 text-align:left;
 background:green;
 margin:0 auto; 
 display:inline-block
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/66fCm/136/

**Anyway, this works perfect :-)
Could anyone mark this post as right answer, because I can`t, due to less reputation.**

[image: Works perfect!]

Answer (score 3):

Just set width of each element 33%
see jsfiddle demo http://jsfiddle.net/4VaRD/2/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="left">left</div>
<div class="center">center</div>
<div class="right">right</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container{
width: 100%;
}
.left{
background-color: red;
float: left;
text-align: left;
width: 33%;
}
.center{
background-color: green;
float: left;
text-align: center;
width: 33%;
}
.right{
background-color: blue;
float: left;
text-align: right;
width: 33%;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget the alignment required by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

you could use display:flex;  see this topic : [Why does display: -ms-flex; -ms-justify-content: center; not work in IE10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17695865/why-display-ms-flex-ms-justify-content-center-dont-work-in-ie10-how-to-p)

or fake it using `inline-block` and `text-align:justify;`
here a codepen example if you want to include older IEs http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/Babcs :

```
<div class="justify">
  <div>Left</div>
  <div>Middle</div>
  <div>Right</div>
  <!--[if lte IE 7]>
     <span class="ie"></span>
  <![endif]-->
</div>
```

Comment: flex is currently not cross-browser compatible, some browser ( currently ) does not / partially support flex boxing. see: http://caniuse.com/flexbox

Comment: that why i propose text-align:justify that works even in IE5.5 and everywhere else as long as you introduce an empty element instead pseudo-elements :)

Comment: some English reading to understand what i'm talking about :) http://www.barrelny.com/blog/text-align-justify-and-rwd/

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your problem, you can get the result by using lists.

So just have the content of the left, center and right divs in list items and use display inline and padding like this:

```
li {
padding: 0 50px 0 0;
display: inline;
}
```

I have made a fiddle for you.
Hope you can use it.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/32B8L/)

Comment: Thank you, Legarndary. I answer my own post, unfortunately I can mark it as answer because I have not enough reputation.

Comment: Glad i could help. Did it help with your problem? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a table actually. This would work well because of table behavior.